# Is there any configuration available to show the toolbar on click of content section

Tags: ckeditor

i have added below configuration to hide the toolbar onload of ckeditor.
config.toolbarStartupExpanded = false;

is there any configuration or any workaround available to show the toolbar once the user clicks on the editing area and then hides it once user clicks out of the editing area.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use **inline** version of editor, it might be sufficient for you in this case.
Take a look into this sample how it works: https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.7.3/full-all/samples/old/inlineall.html.

You need to remember to initialise editor with `CKEDITOR.inline` instead of `CKEDITOR.replace`. More about it you can find in [documentation](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/docs/#!/api/CKEDITOR-method-inline)

Another option might be dynamically create and destroy editor, but this approach might be a little bit more laggy, for the user. Example how it works you can find here: https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.7.3/full-all/samples/old/ajax.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
i am integrating Ckeditor with gwt and the API what is available gwt-ckeditor.jar doesnt have support for inline editing as its very old.
so not able to implement inline editing. so back to the first question is there any way to show the toolbar once i click on the editing area

Comment: In that case I would recommend updating CKEditor folder in `jar` package because CKEditor 3.x is no longer developed and may not work in latest browsers. Please note that it will also be required to change `replace` to `inline` method  in file which inserts CKEditor JavaScript into generated HTML.